# Jeffreys' invariance principle - A doubt on the one-dim case

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, fisher-information

[In this wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior#One-parameter_case) concerning a change of parameterization of a likelihood $L$ from $\theta$ to $\varphi$, why can the $d\theta/d \varphi$ go inside the expectation?

$$\eqalign{
p(\varphi) &= p(\theta)\left|\frac{d\theta}{d\varphi}\right| \propto\sqrt{I(\theta) \left(\frac{d\theta}{d\varphi}\right)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{E\left[\left(\frac{d\,\log(L)}{d\theta}\right)^2\right]\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\varphi}\right)^2} \\
&= \sqrt{E\left[\left(\frac{d\,\log(L)}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{d\varphi}\right)^2\right]}.
}$$

Is it because the expectation is over $\theta$ and not $\varphi$?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fisher information $I(\theta)$ is an expectation over the data $X$ so $\frac{d\theta}{d\phi}$ is constant with respect to it (since $\theta$ and $\phi$ are data-less parameterizations). To be more precise:

$$
I(\theta) = \int_{\mathcal X} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log f(x; \theta) \right)^2 f(x; \theta) dx
$$

so something that is only a function of $\theta$ and $\phi$ is constant with respect to this integral and can be freely moved about. See [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) of the Fisher information for more details.

Comment: +1. Apparently your "$f$" is the same as "$L$" in the referenced Web page.